# How to change blog category, author URL in wordpress

Tags: url-rewriting

I have create a WordPress page with slug blog. I can easily access the blog par with `/blog`.

Now what I want is to add `blog/` in front of all the urls in my blog, like `blog/category/first`, blog/author/pramod..

I have try this by changing category base and author base but it gives me page not found error.

Please let me know is there any other way to do this.

Asked [same question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18846810/how-to-change-blog-category-author-url-in-wordpress) but no reply

Comment: Would moving WordPress to sub-directory help?

Comment: What exactly are your permalink settings right now?